# Path Coordinates In Grid start in Bottom Left vs Top Left

Tags: c#, wpf

Currently, if I enter coordinates 0,0 my point will show up on the top left. While that is the logical and accepted standard, I need to have it be in the bottom left(and all other coordinates adjusted appropriately) because I need to show an accurate representation of graph.

What is the best way to accomplish this in C#/WPF. A solution using a Grid control would be preferable, but not required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [LayoutTransform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.layouttransform.aspx)? You could just set the `Grid.LayoutTransform` equal to a transform that flips the grid as you say:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.LayoutTransform>
        <ScaleTransform ScaleY="-1" />
    </Grid.LayoutTransform>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Because they want the origin to be in the bottom left corner of the graph, a LayoutTransform that flips the graph vertically would be more appropriate, but a LayoutTranform is probably more appropriate than my suggestion.

Comment: flip vertically, not turn 180 degrees, that would result in an origin in the bottom right :)

Comment: How would I add that to a grid in XAML?

Comment: I just updated my answer after actually testing it out this time (Stanislov, this should directly answer your question), to make sure I didnt make anymore stupid mistakes in thought to the transform. :) Thanks @darkmyst

Answer (score 1):

If you know the overall size of your grid, you can subtract your y value from it to get your desired effect. For example:

```
double y = 10.0 // Your desired Y coordinate
double vertical_size = 1000.0; // The graph is 1000 pixes high
double adjusted_y = vertical_size - y; // 990, which is y pixels from the bottom of the graph
```